# pie chart in html and js

Tags: javascript, html

hello all i used canvas to create pie chart by surfing through stackoverflow and i found the below code but i need only for 2 values instead of 5 because  my pie chart doesnt appear fully .below **chv2** and **chs2** are js values

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var lastend = 0;
 var data = [chv2, chs2]; // If you add more data values make sure you add more colors
 var myTotal = 0; // Automatically calculated so don't touch
 var myColor = ['red', 'green']; // Colors of each slice

 for (var e = 0; e < data.length; e++) {
   myTotal += data[e];
 }
 alert(myTotal);

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
   // Arc Parameters: x, y, radius, startingAngle (radians), endingAngle (radians), antiClockwise (boolean)
   ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 2, lastend, lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / myTotal)), false);
   ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
   ctx.fill();
   lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / myTotal);
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

Comment: Are you expected this output https://jsfiddle.net/pbb0pyhx/.

Comment: @balachandar yep needed the chart as a full circle but only for 2 values

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the **chv2** and **chs2** varible declaration.

Please check this code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var lastend = 0;
var chv2= 20;
var chs2= 40;
var data = [chv2,chs2]; // If you add more data values make sure you add more colors
var myTotal = 0; // Automatically calculated so don't touch
var myColor = ['red','green']; // Colors of each slice

for (var e = 0; e < data.length; e++) {
  myTotal += data[e];
}
alert(myTotal);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  // Arc Parameters: x, y, radius, startingAngle (radians), endingAngle (radians), antiClockwise (boolean)
  ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 2, lastend, lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / myTotal)), false);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.fill();
  lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / myTotal);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbb0pyhx/1/)

Hope this will help you.